# excluding string and limiting the filter length in regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex. I want to

1. Filter patter of length 8-14 only.
2. Excluding number 123456789 from regex matching

regex:

```
^(?=.{8,14})b$\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}
```

this is ok, but problem is, it filters numbers with length greater then 14 also.

Here is above regex to exclude `123456789` from filtering.

```
^(?=.{8,14})b$^(?!123456789)\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}
```

But this does not exclude it. What wrong I am doing here.

**UPDATE1**

```
sample input : "I will call you on 2034561278 number"
sample output: "I will call you on ********** number"


sample input : "I will call you on 20345612781234567 number"
sample output: "I will call you on 20345612781234567 number" (length > 14)
```

**UPDATE2**

```
    $text = 'I will call you on 20345612781234567 number';
$resultSet = array();
    $pattern = '/^(?=.{8,14})b$\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    $this->pushToResultSet($matches);   
return $resultSet;
```

Comment: What are you doing with the patterns when you find them? And could you add input and expected output?

Comment: I highly recommend that you do not attempt to validate telephone numbers with regular expressions. Even in the UK (inferred from your expression), where public number allocation is closely regulated and well defined, there are odd exceptions to the rules, and (much like email address validation) verifying that the number pattern is technically valid does not guarantee that it exists. Either your users want to give you their telephone number, in which case they will give you something valid, or they do not, in which case no amount of pattern validation will make them give you the right number.

Comment: **Pro-tip:** use the `x` modifier and add some spacing/indentation to your regex. It's a mess now, who wants to debug/understand that?

Comment: @HamZa I'm afraid that's not going to help. Open one of those gigabyte beauties in debuggex.com and you'll see it's an excercise in futility with or without formatting.

Comment: @DaveRandom: thanks dude, your point is valid, I will look for any other alternative. But currently I have to carry on with this

Comment: Yep. You see this on any site that tries to filter telephone numbers (which is what it looks like you're doing). The users will find a way to either get around your filter, or give you bad data when you're trying to validate it. "2one34567eight90", sorry filter. "123~345~7890" sorry validator, I'm cool and use tildes. Meh. It isn't the case that this is never attempted, but it is the case that this never works out completely as intended.

Comment: @Chris: do you have any suggestion for `2one34567eight90` exploit? I am trying to figure it out and on mid way. By the way I appreciate your help for this particular question too

Comment: @Programming_crazy I get what you are trying now, and users will always get around them. What about: `555-123456` or `555 . 47473` or `Call me on +5 151 BESTDEALS` as some marketers do.

Comment: @Programming_crazy I think that no matter what you think of, someone will think of a way around it unless you replace every numeric character in the string, and every number word... not practical. I think, instead of trying to catch them all, you should simplify and catch the common and obvious, then rely on human moderation for the rest. Craigslist has moderators, StackOverflow has moderators... not everything can be software problem. When the only tool you consider is a hammer, all problems start to look like nails.

Comment: @Programming_crazy Jack's answer is what I mean -- just look for a phone number outright, if you find it, filter it, if they're trying to be sneaky, then you deal with that. If it is a big deal that they tried to be sneaky, ban them. If not, just manually filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\b\d{8,14}\b/', function($match) {
    if ($match[0] == '123456789') {
        return $match[0];
    } else {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($match[0]));
    }            
}, $str);
```

#### Update

```
if (preg_match_all('/\b\d{8,14}\b/', $str, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        if ($match != '123456789') {
            $this->pushToResultSet($match);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont want to replact it with `*`. I am just returning match as I have shown in UPDATE2. can you please correct regex to limit 8-14 mumber?

Comment: @Programming_crazy You shouldn't update your question to change the expected outcome, the answers will suffer for it.

Comment: apologize. can you please see why this regex match for number length > 14 too, http://regex101.com/r/iF0dE0

Comment: @Programming_crazy No, because I prefer to keep my sanity, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you absoultely need to match these using regular expression, I'd suggest taking an iterative approach, using separate matches, using the "cheapest" ones first, and progressively using more exhaustive ones.

This will both make the individual regular expression easier to read, make the code easier to read, and will ensure that you aren't performing processor intensive matches on strings which can easily be determined to be wrong.

For example in some strange pseudo code:

```
FUNCTION CHECK ($MYNUMBER) {
    IF "123456789" is in $MYNUMBER:
        RETURN $ERROR
    IF LEN $MYNUMBER < 9 or LEN $MYNUMBER > 14:
        RETURN $ERROR
    IF $MYNUMBER not matches $CRAZY_REGEX:
        RETURN $ERROR
    RETURN $NOT_ERROR
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I could not manually check for it to exist in text. Please see I am not getting this no `123456789` or similar other seperately. It is part of text, which I dont want to filter out. I appreciate if you can give some hint to improve regex in my question

Comment: @Programming_crazy I don't understand what you said. Surely there is some PHP code calling the regex. Alter the PHP to take care of some of the more complex logical edge cases and this will be much simpler. As people have stated, your regex is too complex for either a program, user or another developer to comprehend.

Comment: The misunderstanding here is that he is not looking to validate, he is looking to filter. Craigslist does this, if I recall. If you post your number (in one of the highly specific ways that they anticipated), they will replace it with asterisks.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: I am sorry I could not make it clear. but Chris gave correct point

Comment: @Chris Ah thanks for that. I got it now. And "ways they anticipate" is the operative phrase there. Users are very sneaky when it comes to getting around filters like that - ask me about it by electronic mail: `sneaky_user(at)i_am_so_clever(dot)org`